# ImageView not respecting constraints

Tags: ios, xcode, autolayout

Simple `UIImageView`. Direct child of the main view. Pinned to all four corners. When I run it on iPhone 6+ there are margins on the left and right. What am I missing?

Here is how it looks in the storyboard:

[image]

Here are its constraints:

[image]

And here is how it looks when I run it:

[image]

Comment: YOur imageview is not contstrained to the superview properly. The constraints have the value -16. It should be 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two possibilities:

- Unfortunately, the Size inspector fails to show you a crucial distinction. It says that the leading and trailing constraints are to the "superview". But in fact they might be to the superview *margin*. This would then account for the extra space.
- With an image view, everything depends on its *content mode*. You have not revealed what this is, but it can make a huge difference. It could be that the image *view* is being placed correctly but it is drawing its *image* in an undesirable way.

Comment: That was it. I had the content mode set wrong. Arrgh. Lots of wasted time. Thank you!